# How can I get all the remote method and end-point/properties of a model in loopback 3?

Tags: loopbackjs

I am trying to find out all the remote method of model and its end-point/properties ? How can I get it in loopback 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are similar discussions on github:

- [get all remote methods for managing permission](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/2421)
- [List remote methods added by relations](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1557)

Below is the code they recommend to use to get all the remote methods for a particular model:

```
function getActiveRemoteMethods(model) {
  const activeRemoteMethods = model.sharedClass
    .methods({ includeDisabled: false })
    .reduce((result, sharedMethod) => {
      Object.assign(result, {
        [sharedMethod.name]: sharedMethod.isStatic,
      });
      return result;
    }, {});

  return activeRemoteMethods;
}
```